# A local algebra is flat if and only if it is faithfully flat.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be local rings and $A\to B$ be a local algebra (that is, the image of $A$'s maximal ideal is contained in $B$'s maximal ideal). In order to prove that $B$ flat implies $B$ faithfully flat, my textbook proves first that

> A $A$-module $M$ is faithfully flat iff $M\otimes_A (A/\mathfrak{m})\neq 0$ for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subset A$.

Then the author proceeds to say that our result follows immediately. I don't understand how. Since $A$ is a local ring, it suffices to show that

$$B\otimes_A (A/\mathfrak{m})\neq 0,$$
where $\mathbb{m}$ is $A$'s maximal ideal. If $B$ was finitely generated as a $A$-module, then this is basically Nakayama's lemma. But the author does not suppose this. Is there another way to prove this?

P.S. the textbook is *Álgebra Comutativa em Quatro Movimentos* by Eduardo Tengan and Herivelto Borges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $B\otimes (A/\mathfrak m)\cong B/\mathfrak mB\neq 0,$ since  $\mathfrak mB$ is contained in the maximal ideal of $B $.